# Disable SMS and Email Notifications in Android

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

Is there any way within (or non-standard way) to disable email and sms alerts / notifications when an Android application is running?  I found a way to mute the phone ringer, but I want to stop the audio / vibrate alerts from occuring.  I've seen some bed time clock apps that mute notifications and they work fine.

Any thoughts to how to code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html):

```
AudioManager aM = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
aM.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
aM.setVibrateSetting (AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF)
```

---

```
public void setRingerMode (int ringerMode)
```

> Since: API Level 1
>
> Sets the ringer mode.
>
> Silent mode will mute the volume and will not vibrate. Vibrate mode will mute the volume and vibrate. Normal mode will be audible and may vibrate according to user settings.
>
> Parameters
>
> ringerMode    The ringer mode, one of RINGER_MODE_NORMAL, RINGER_MODE_SILENT, or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.
>
> ---

```
public void setVibrateSetting (int vibrateType, int vibrateSetting)
```

> Since: API Level 1
>
> Sets the setting for when the vibrate type should vibrate.
>
> This method should only be used by applications that replace the platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony application.
>
> Parameters
>
> vibrateType   The type of vibrate. One of VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION or VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER.
>
> vibrateSetting    The vibrate setting, one of VIBRATE_SETTING_ON, VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF, or VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT.

Comment: Thank you. You got me one step closer. Is there a way to disable the audio notifications too? I have the ringer off, the vibrate off, but when an email or SMS comes in, the audio beep still plays. Do you know how to shut that off?

Comment: Looks like this is also needed.  Thanks!  audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);